# Redis multiple cluster with node js

Tags: json, node.js, redis

We are trying to add another redis slave to the existing configuration of a master and a slave. We are using redis in a node app, where we are configuring redis master and slave like below in json file.

```
"redis" : {
"master" : {
"host" : "x.x.x.x."
},
"slave" :{
"host" : "x.x.x.x."
}}
```

As this is JSON, i can't add a new key as "slave". Could any one tell me how can I configure this?

Comment: Slaves are read-only you must configure `redis.conf` for more. https://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: Which Node Redis client are you using? Is your Redis running in cluster or stand-alone (single master) mode?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix - Yes, slaves are configured as read-only.

Comment: @ItamarHaber - I'm using node_redis (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). "name": "redis",  "version": "0.7.2".  At the moment, I have a master and slave setup and looking to add one more slave to the existing configuration. I can't configure another slave in the config.json and looking at other options on how to add this extra slave? I'm using master for writes and slaves are read-only.

Comment: You can't add a key to an read-only slave , you should have an connection to master which you use for writing , slaves are synced automatically later.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix .. Yes, I understand that. I'm not asking whether I can use a slave to write. I need the extra slave for reads, but i'm not sure on how to configure it using node js app?

Comment: don't know I node_redis supports that, just create different connections etc, ioredis supports multiple slaves for reading